# Facebook PHP: check access_token, when user is offline

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

How to check from my website, whether access_token of user is valid, when the user is currently offline? (Or even logged in user is another than user I wish to check?)

Most of tutorials about checking token_access works for current logged users using path '/me'.

But I wish to check any user of my FB app.
I will need a method like (pseudocode)

```
$facebook->checkAccessToken($token);
```

I have saved user's tokens in my db and I would like to get feedback from fb, whether the tokens are still valid.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token='.$USER_TOKEN.'&access_token='.$APP_TOKEN;
$a = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: For further explanation, this is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug

Answer (score 1):

Offline Access is deprecated and does not exist anymore. The way to go nowadays is to extend the short living access tokens.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Take a look on the chapter "Expiration and Extending Tokens". Basically you have to query the graph API and send some app-specific parameters. What you're about to get returned is your long living token.

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
client_id={app-id}&
client_secret={app-secret}&
fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

(Taken from official docs)

**Note that even a long lived token will expire any time. Use the Graph API explorer to get details on the access token.**

The meat and potatoes is not to hope that you generate a token that won't expire, but to have a clean authenthication flow once your token expired. Implement checks on expired tokens. Refresh the token on the users next visit. That's half the battle!

Happy Coding!

Comment: Lol I noticed that I totally missed your questions purpose. Sorry for that. David's answer is totally correct in this case. If you're going to accept an answer as correct take davids.